# How test if a pdf is already open - with Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

We have an Excel spreadsheet that produces Invoices. We now need to convert the spreadsheet to pdf for emailing to the customer.

I have written a macro that 'at the touch of a button' produces the .pdf and displays it (in an Acrobat reader window).

However, if the user intentionaly, or inadvertently presses the button a 2nd time while the Acrobat window is still open - the macro errors.

The macro is:

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
'
' SaveAsPDF Macro
'

'
    Application.Goto Reference:="Print_Area"

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    'add 'Document Properties' CustomerName & CustOrderRef to the pdf doc.
    ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("title").Value = Range("H13").Value & "-ref:" & Range("H14") & "-" & FormatCurrency(Range("J115").Value, 2)

    'get Inv# and CustomerName
    'ThisFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Inv" & Range("H15").Value & "-" & Range("H13").Value & ".pdf"
    ThisFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Inv.pdf"

    MsgBox "The info. will now be copied to create a PDF Invoice." & vbCrLf & "Which will be saved in the 'Invoices' folder as:" & vbCrLf & ThisFile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please press OK, and when the PDF window opens - print 2 copies on Invoice Stationery." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The PDF then can be closed.  (its already been saved)"
    '*** Note - this code arrors if pdf is already open !  ***


    'Create pdf. save it and display it on-screen - for user to print
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                filename:=ThisFile, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=True

    'save & close the spreadsheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit


End Sub




Function IsFileOpen(fileFullName As String)
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim errorNum As Integer

    'MgBox "123" & fileFullName

    On Error Resume Next
    FileNumber = FreeFile()   ' Assign a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open fileFullName For Input Lock Read As #FileNumber
    Close FileNumber       ' Close the file.
    errorNum = Err         ' Assign the Error Number which occured
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking on.
    ' Now Check and see which error occurred and based
    ' on that you can decide whether file is already
    ' open
    Select Case errorNum
        ' No error occurred so ErroNum is Zero (0)
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied." is 70
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' For any other Error occurred
        Case Else
            Error errorNum
    End Select

End Function
```

I found (in StackOverflow) macros to test if a file is open (with another user) and others see: Function `IsFileOpen` above.
But I can't get them working for me.  e.g. `IsFileOpen` errors with

> Error errorNum

How can I best/easiest test:

1. Does the file exist?
2. If so, is it already open for reading?

Comment: The `IsFileOpen` function looks good to test that. So what error number do you get?

Answer (score 0):

For *"1. Does the file exist?"*:

```
Public Function fp_FilExs(pPne$) As Boolean
    fp_FilExs = CBool(LenB(Dir$(pPne, vbNormal)))
End Function
```

.

For *"2. If so, is it already open for reading?"*:
Try code below.
`Tools --> Options --> General --> Error Trapping` option
must be less than `Break on all errors`.

However it is NOT a comprehensive solution for all cases.
With text file, opened and even edited in Notepad++, for example, it's not work...

```
Public Function fp_InUse(pPne$) As Boolean
Dim iFreFil%
    iFreFil = FreeFile
On Error Resume Next
    Open pPne For Input Lock Read Write As #iFreFil
    fp_InUse = CBool(Err.Number)
    Close #iFreFil
End Function
```

.
Also look on [more sophisticated solution here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/fileapi/createfile_inuse.htm) ,
which return following states:

```
   Select Case bResult
      Case FILE_IN_USE
         Label1.Caption = "File in use"
      Case FILE_FREE
         Label1.Caption = "File is available"
      Case FILE_DOESNT_EXIST
         Label1.Caption = "File does not exist!"
   End Select
```

.